# Calling a method asynchronously

Tags: c#

I have a method named `X()`. I need to call that method asynchronously. Can anyone give sample code for this?

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of ways, involving threads and delegates. Here's one example using the thread pool:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => { X(); });
```

And here's one involving delegates:

```
Func<string> del = X;
del.BeginInvoke(ar => 
{
    Func<string> endDel = (Func<string>)ar.AsyncState;
    var result = endDel.EndInvoke(ar);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}, del);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your really lost on threading with C#, the BackgroundWorker is a good place to start. It handles a simple DoWork method to run your asynchronis calls and an OnComplete event to do any UI manipulation when the thread returns.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx